# AllowNull Attribute in c#8 for netstandard2.0 and net451 raise compilation error

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Environment: vs 2019 v16.3.1

in c# netstandard2.0 and net451 project, I use c# 8 nulable reference with attributes.

Enable c# 8 in csproj:

```
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

In myclass.cs, I use AllowNullAttribute:

```
     class My class {
       [AllowNull]
     public T MyValue {get;set;}
     }
```

When building the project, I get a compilation error:

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'AllowNullAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ConsoleApp1 (netstandard2.0)

The documentation [Attributes extend type annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes#attributes-extend-type-annotations) include these types

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken. I don't think C# 8 is compatible with netstandard 2.0 and net451

Comment: There is no reference in c# 8 docs to exclude these frameworks, see my [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes#attributes-extend-type-annotations) in the question.

Comment: @ Herohtar, thanks for link. It help to know the limitation for c#8 in net frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# 8 (and therefore, by extension, AllowNull) does not seem to be fully supported in netstandard 2.0.

For example, if you go to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.allownullattribute?view=netcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.0) for AllowNull and select .NET Standard 2.0 as the version, you will get the following message:

> The requested page is not available for .NET Standard 2.0. You have
>   been redirected to the newest product version this page is available
>   for.

Also see [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2877). Namely,

> Officially, C# 8.0 is only supported on runtimes that adhere to the
>   .NET Standard 2.1. That does not (and will not) include .NET Framework
>   4.x.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Only attributes are suported in netstandard2.1 and netcore3.0.